# Setting up Python Interpreter in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse

Having installed anaconda, I was trying to set up the python interpreter in eclipse. After the installation, I noticed there are no packages.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? I see that other people's pages have packages but my does not. I was able to find python.exe under the pkge folder in anaconda 3 which is all I was asked to do during the installation process.

EDIT 1: Thank you for your help, I have the python interpreter set up. However, when I made a test project and tried to import numpy, It was giving me an error. Isn't numpy something that comes with anaconda?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Inside the folder where you install Anaconda3, there is the `python.exe` file.
And inside the folder `python-3.6` in the `pkgs` folder also.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure if you get a notification if I update the question but I am getting errors with importing numpy. If you can help, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: No, you need to install it. Open Anaconda promt and run `pip install numpy`.

Comment: I ran the line but is says its already installed. It does mention that something I don't know anything about isn't installed. Maybe that could be the issue? I put up another screenshot.

Comment: It said that the PyHamcrest was missed, so install it `pip install pyhamcrest`. And then install numpy again. Then use `pip list` to check that it has been installed.

Comment: Just ran both lines again and tried to execute the same code in eclipse. It still gives me the same error though. I posted a couple more screenshots. Thank you.

Comment: I've looked up the error and found that maybe it's because of multiple versions of python in your machine. Try this out `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall numpy`.

Comment: Yeah I think that worked! I just ran that line and tried running the import statement in eclipse and no errors. If I wanted to do the same thing with matplotlib, would I just do the same line but replace numpy with matplotlib?

Comment: Sure. Now you can install any package that you want. Remember to run it in the Anaconda prompt